# spring integration java DSL for complex business logic

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

We have most of our application logic using typical Springboot components.

We are looking at using spring boot integration. The flow is to provision servie for end user. Typically we get a request and it has to orchestrate by calling a bunch of other services, with conditional branching and the end result is the user is provisioned.

What is the best way to implement this in Spring integration ? Is there any way to link them dynamically based on the output of the previous step ?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AbstractMappingMessageRouter` has a *dynamic channels* feature. So, you can route to whatever channel you want and it is really going to be tied at runtime: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/5.0.9.RELEASE/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#dynamic-routers